# shortcut key to give values for boiler plate code in xcode iOS

Tags: xcode

[image]

Here we need to click each one to give values, Is any keyboard shortcut available for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> Direction Left to Right.

Also by <kbd>tab</kbd> Direction Left to Right.

If you want to go backward <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>+ <kbd>/</kbd> Direction Right to Left.

Also by <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. Direction Right to Left.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate though them using 'Tab' key.